# Angular2 Server-side rendering of main app.module

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I'm fairly new to Angular2, so apologies if there is an obvious answer or if I'm misunderstanding the way server-side rendering works.

We have an Angular2 project, initially based on [Steven Sanderson's .net core template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/), with server-side rendering etc, but we've upgraded webpack and Angular a couple of times since.

We've had to disable the server-side rendering because we're using devexpress for Angular2 ([issue here](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/issues/46)), alongside a couple of other libraries that don't sit very well with server-side rendering.

Our project has now grown to a significant size, and we'd really like to have the server-side rendering back on due to the perceived performance increase, but we can't remove our dependency on the devexpress libraries.

My question is: would it be possible to split the project into modules, with all the code using the libraries that can't be server-side rendered in lazy-loaded modules, and then pre-render the main app.module?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I would look elsewhere for performance issues before attempting to make the server-side rendering work. Put some numbers on your "perceived performance issues" before going down that road.

Comment: By my knowledge, server side rendering has almost no performance gain, compared to AOT. Are you using AOT in the current state of your project?

Comment: @sdotdi the "percieved performance" I'm talking about is the "loading" of the Angular app - which from PierreDuc's answer looks like is the JIT compiler.

I wasn't aware that AOT was a thing, so I'll set that up and report back. 

Thanks!