# Angular2 AOT Compilation with static external js file

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

Directed by the answer to [my question about Server-side rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733503/angular2-server-side-rendering-of-main-app-module), I'm looking at implementing AOT compilation in my Angular2 app.

A bit of background to the problem I'm having: we have a build running in Visual Studio Online, which runs webpack etc, and ships a functioning webapp. We then have a release in VSO to different environments which puts some values (environment, base urls, important keys) into an `env-config.js` file. This `env-config.js` file is not bundled and packaged within the app, but we access it as a global js variable within our Angular code.

**env-config.js**

```
var envConfig = {
    'environment': 'local',
    'baseApiUrl': 'localhost:5555',
}
```

Within `app-config.ts`, we access `envConfig` from the window object, store this as a constant, and export the constant `AppConfig`, which we then register in `app.module` using an `OpaqueToken`.

**app-config.ts**

```
export function getEnvConfig(): IAppEnvConfig {
    if (window == null) {
        return {
            'environment': '',
            'baseApiUrl': ''
        };
    }
    else {
        return (window as any).envConfig;
    }
}

export const _envConfig: IAppEnvConfig = getEnvConfig();

export const AppConfig: IAppConfig = {
    applicationName: 'Web Application',
    environment: _envConfig.environment,
    baseApiUrl: _envConfig.baseApiUrl,
    otherSetting: 'someValue'
}
```

This works really well running in the browser with the JIT compiler. I'm following a combination of [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) and [this](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/02/08/angular-2-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation-lazy-loading-treeshaking-webpack/) and other tutorials to enable AOT compilation.

Running ngc gives me the following error:

```
"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p app/tsconfig-aot.json Error encountered 
resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'getEnvConfig',  
function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda 
with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppConfig
```

I added the check for `window == null` in `getEnvConfig()` because I don't think `window` will be available during non-browser compilation. If `getEnvConfig()` does anything other than return an empty `IAppEnvConfig` object I get the ngc error.

I have done a lot of Googling, but have found nothing specific to my issue, other than generic answers pointing towards using a factory function to create a new instance of a class, which I've tried to do here.

Sorry if that doesn't make much sense - please feel free to get clarification/tell me that I'm doing something incredibly stupid.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solution will fit you, but I post it any way. I faced the same issue and foud the problem was quite easy to solve. Simply put your functions in a class. Something like this:

```
export class AppConfig {
  _envConfig = AppConfig.getEnvConfig();
  AppConfig = {
    applicationName: 'Web Application',
    environment: this._envConfig.environment,
    baseApiUrl: this._envConfig.baseApiUrl,
    otherSetting: 'someValue'
  };

  static getEnvConfig() {
    if (window == null) {
      return {
        'environment': '',
        'baseApiUrl': ''
      };
    } else {
      return (window as any).envConfig;
    }
  }

  private constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you register this in your app.module.ts so that you can use it with the DI? Do you still use the OpaqueToken or just inject like you would a service?

Comment: Well, this is just a regular class so I doný think you need DI. I have never worked with OpaqueToken, however I read someting about it being replaced with InjectionToken. Never the less, this all seems like overkill to me sinds the CLI has a build-in option for this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: In progress, basically following your answer :) however, rather than having AppConfig exported as an object, I'm setting the config values as class properties. When it works, I'll accept your answer!